# In how many ways can the new staff be allocated at random?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Can anyone help me with this one out please,

Universal Temps is recruiting for people to work at $5$ call centres, and there are $10$ applicants.

Assume that all call centres have at least $10$ vacancies.

(a) In how many ways can the new staff be allocated at random?

(b) If allocation is random, what is the probability that at least one new staff member is assigned to each call centre?

---

For a) Is $10^5$  correct? Solved.

And b) $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6$ divided by $5^{10}$?

Comment: Can you explain your processes, i.e. how you got to your answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not correct.

a) should be $5^{10}$: person 1 has 5 options, person 2 has 5 options, ...

b) is also not correct.  Try calculating the number of ways in which *some* call center does *not* get anyone.

Comment: Can't figure out the b) part
Is it (10*9*8*7*6)/5^10?

Comment: @Synotaxidae  No.  Try using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Sorry about reviving this thread, but the question is verbatim from a statistics textbook. I think that your answer is correct, but this question was used in an assignment for one of my university courses. The correct solution was given as $14\choose 4$. I think that your solution is correct and the markers have made an error here, but I'm going through this thread struggling to justify why I was given an incorrect solution.

Comment: @RoryGrice This is for b)?

Comment: part a), the solution that they gave for part b) was ${9\choose4}\over{14\choose4}$, though I suspect that this is also incorrect. edit - the only way that this answer could be correct is by accident as the denominator is derived from an incorrect solution for a)

Comment: @RoryGrice Ah, ok, I see what is going on: they are merely looking at how many people each center gets, not which specific individuals. That is, if Bob and John would end up in different call centers, but they swap places, it would actually be considered the same distribution of people, since the number at each center remains the same. OK, so to solve  that problem, you use the starts and bars method ... look it up and you'll understand!

Comment: ahhhhhhh, starts and bars.

Comment: Stars and bars, sorry !

Comment: @RoryGrice I think you could make a case for this question being unclear ... I certainly misunderstood what they were asking!